Silent Authentication from Browsers using Ubunut, Linux, gssapi and PHP
I have previously relied on NTLM for silent authentication for a number of Internal intranet sites but the latest Windows 11 release has stopped these from working.  I have built a new Linux box (Ubuntu 24.04) and installed Apache and PHP.  Using the guide found at https://docs.typo3.org/p/causal/ig_ldap_sso_auth/main/en-us/SSO/Configuration.html I have managed to get authentication working using gssapi but not silently.
Here is my virtual host file
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin ops@mycompany.com
    ServerName it_intranet.mycompany.com
    ServerAlias it_intranet
    DocumentRoot /var/www/it_intranet
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/it_intranet_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/it_intranet_access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/cert_2024_2025.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server_2024_2025.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/cert_2024_2025.pem
   <Directory /var/www/it_intranet>
      Options FollowSymlinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
   <Location />
                SSLRequireSSL
                AuthType GSSAPI
                AuthName "IT Intranet for Company"
                GssapiBasicAuth On
                GssapiCredStore keytab:/etc/apache2/it_intranet.keytab
                GssapiLocalName On
                require valid-user
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>

When I browse to the page I am asked for my username and password.  Entering in correct details shows me the page and incorrect details give me a 401 Unauthorized so I know correct authentication is happening.
But I need this to be silent.  Can anyone help please?
